# DataBase access using Loader

Tags: java, android

I have made a local database.I have accessing it using diffrent methods but i think CursorLoader is the efficient way to access it.But i don't know know how to do it.Can anyone help?Here is my code

```
 Main Activity
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    TextView t1;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    List<Info> infoList;
    String arrr;
    int ar;
    int Loader_id=1;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


        List<Info> infos = db.getAllInfo();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDivider(Main2Activity.this));

        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, infos);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```

DataBaseHandler

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Dispalymanager";
    private static final String TABLE = "contacts";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_AGE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    void addInfo(Info info) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, info.getName());
        values.put(KEY_AGE, info.getAge());
        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    Info getinfo(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Info info = new Info(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        return info;
    }

    public List<Info> getAllInfo() {
        List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<Info>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Info contact = new Info();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                infoList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return infoList;
    }

    public int updateInfo(Info info) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, info.getName());
        values.put(KEY_AGE, info.getAge());


        return db.update(TABLE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(info.getID())});
    }

    public void deleteInfo(Info contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE, KEY_NAME + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getName())});
        db.close();
    }


    public int getInfoCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();


        return count;
    }

    boolean deleteitem(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from "+TABLE+" where "+KEY_ID+" ="+id);

        return  true;

    }

}
```

Comment: inside `onCreateLoader` return a new `CursorLoader` and use your `Cursor data` inside `onLoadFinished` method

Comment: But how will i connect it to my database

Comment: in a custom `ContentProvider`, or if you dont want that use some custom `Loader` that uses local sqlite db directly - but you will need to find it somewhere on the web

Comment: Can you recommend me some tutorial coz i searched it but found nothing.

Comment: what you searched?

Comment: custom ContentProvider,but not found something useful

Comment: try `loader cursor sqlitedatabase`